# Search for matches and save and maybe replace it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

i'll try to explain my question in the best way i can ...
okay.

i have a multi line string like this:

```
Hello World
And again Hello <a:b:c>
And again ...
```

Now i want to replace  but it depents on what is the first letter, the second and so on. I have a regex snippet to get an array with the 3 arguments.

```
arr = ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

now i have a switch to analyse the first argument.

```
switch (arr[0]) {
         case 'a':
              // do this
         [...]
}
```

if the first argument is a i want to replace `<a:b:c>` with something.

The question is now:
To get the arguments i use preg_split. How its now possible to replace the right part of the string ? I can get the position with `PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE` but its a multi line string, and (!) when i replace  with something the position of the other matches (there are n-matches possible) must be change too, right ?

Maybe you have a solution to solve this ?

I thought preg_replace could be work, but i think this is the wrong function to solve this, because an letter (for example the second, `b`) can be a parameter that is dynamic. Maybe i understood the function preg_replace in the wrong way ... but ... i really dont know how to solve this. Maybe you have a documentation where i can read something to solve this problem (please dont link me to php.net - i already read it) or you have a an idea.

Comment: you are looking for `preg_maybe_replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This function will replace specific matches into a new form
function RewriteText($Match)
{
  $EntireSection = $Match[0];
  $GroupOne = $Match[1];
  // ...
  return $Value;
}

$NewText = preg_replace_callback('/Hello\s+(\S+)/i', "RewriteText", $Text);
```

Comment: This solved the problem and it works fine! Thanks for your answer! I never heard about this function before - but now its saved in my head.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace text in a string - but the replacement is based purely off of the first character found in the match?

If this is right, you can use PHP's [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Something similar to the following should work:

```
function replace_callback($matches) {
    switch ($matches[0]) {
        case 'a': return 'whatever';
    }
}

$str = preg_replace_callback('/<([a-z]):([a-z]):([a-z])>/ig', "replace_callback", $str);
```